# Problem switching to functional component react with useEffect

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, d3.js

I'm currently trying to change a class component (working) into a functional component (not working). Basically, my goal is to make the element centered at the page.

EDIT: If anyone can comment what `ref={tc=>(this.treeContainer=tc)}` does, it will be extremely helpful too!

My class component (that works):

```
/** 
 * Component returning a div containing a tree
 * Need to declare as class for ComponentDidMount() 
 */
class CenterMe extends React.PureComponent {

    state={}

    /* Used to center the tree on render */
    componentDidMount() {
      const dimensions = this.treeContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
      this.setState({
        translate: {
          x: 30,
          y: dimensions.height / 2
        }
      });
    }

    /* Returns the actual tree content */
    render(){
      return(
          <div class="treeWrapper" ref={tc => (this.treeContainer = tc)}>
              <Tree
                  translate = {this.state.translate}
              />
          </div>
      );
    }
}
```

My current functional component look like this and does not work:

```
function CenterMe() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({translate:{x:0,y:0}); // Added thanks to @jstu

    /* Used to center the tree on render */
    useEffect(()=> {
      const dimensions = treeContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
      setState({
        translate: {
          x: 30,
          y: dimensions.height / 2
        }
      });
    });

    /* Returns the actual tree content */
      return(
          <div class="treeWrapper" ref={tc => (this.treeContainer = tc)}>
              <Tree
                  translate = {this.state.translate}
              />
          </div>
      );
}
```

More specifically, it is complaining that setState and treeContainer are not defined. 
If it matters, the Tree component is imported from react-d3-tree and the translate function basically does quite literally what it says - it moves the tree.
I think the problem is mainly focused on `ref={tc=>(this.treeContainer=tc)}`, so explanation on that can also help. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you seem to have missed the state hook. Try this

```
    function CenterMe() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({translate:{x:0,y:0}}); // Set an initial state
    const treeContainer = useRef(null);

        /* Used to center the tree on render */
        useEffect(()=> {
          const dimensions = treeContainer.current.getBoundingClientRect();
          setState({
            translate: {
              x: 30,
              y: dimensions.height / 2
            }
          });
        },[]);

        /* Returns the actual tree content */
          return(
              <div class="treeWrapper" ref={treeContainer}>
                  <Tree
                      translate = {state.translate}
                  />
              </div>
          );
    }
```

I haven't tested this. but what you are missing is the useState hook.
Also just noticed that you mean to implement componentDidMount. so you need to pass an empty array at the end. So that it behaves as componentDidMount

Comment: Aah, thanks - it's no longer complaining about setState, but still can't seem to identify treeContainer. Any insight on that?

Comment: Sorry i missed that part. updating answer

Comment: Thanks so much! That fixed my problem. I'll go ahead and accept this

Answer (score 2):

You need to use add two hooks `useRef` and `useState` in order to make the conversion

```
function CenterMe() {
 const [translate, setTranslate] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
 const treeContainer = useRef(null)

 /* Used to center the tree on render */
 useEffect(()=> {
  const dimensions = treeContainer.current.getBoundingClientRect();
  setTranslate({
      x: 30,
      y: dimensions.height / 2
  });
 }, []);

/* Returns the actual tree content */
  return(
      <div class="treeWrapper" ref={treeContainer}>
          <Tree
              translate={translate}
          />
      </div>
  );
}
```

The useState is to replace the setState from the class based component and the useRef will give you the current reference if you access the treeContainer.current key.

To explain for what is the ref part, basically the ref in your case is referencing a dom node, for example if your tree component looks like this:

```
<div className="awesome-class">
 <p>Hi</p>
</div>
```

what the use ref is doing here is that it will give you the dom element ref which would look like this assuming the tree component is like the above example.

```
    <div class="treeWrapper">
     <div className="awesome-class">
      <p>Hi</p>
     </div>
    </div>
```

With the ref you are getting the element from the dom, for example in your specific case `getBoundingClientRect` will give you the size of that specific element, this is very useful as you can see because you're able to use the children values in the parent component. More info of using the hook here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: Thanks so much for the insight! Upvoted. Also note to anyone else who stumbles upon this question: Remember to pass in [ ] as a second argument to useEffect, so everything does not get stuck in updating

Comment: I just updated the question with the array in the useEffect and the explanation of the ref part

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so a couple of things. 
Use state returns an array which can be deconstructed with syntax []. Like this

```
    const [someName, setSomeName] = useState({
        translateX: 10,
        translateY: 20 
    })
```

You are giving useState an anonymus function. I dont know if you can do that, never done it before.

But try the the solution i wrote above. Set value for translatioY by calling that method and then in Tree component do this.

```
<Tree  translate = {someName}/>
```

And for ref you have to use useRef() hook